# What is my net salary in California out of 150k$?

Tags: usa, california, salary

I would like to know the take-home from a 150k$ salary in California, after all kind of deductions, including a good health insurance.

My second question is the estimated cost for renting a studio or small 1-2br flat in SF or Santa Clara, San Jose.

Comment: You should really split that into two questions. Also, that's a very big area you're interested in, rent will vary a lot across that zone

Comment: Assuming you're an expatriate, please edit your question to include what is your citizenship, migration status and how long will you be in the US? These factors can affect your taxes significantly.

Comment: Also be aware that we have a [money.se] site to handle finance questions that don't have an Expatriate angle.

Answer (score 1):

Both questions cannot really be answered without more details.

You can find tax estimators online (you can use [paycheck estimators](http://www.paycheckcity.com/calculator/salary/) or [tax estimators](http://www.hrblock.com/get-answers/tax-calculators.html)) to get an idea.

Re rents - just look at [craigslist](http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sby/apa) for units that seem to fit your criteria and check the prices. Keep in mind that there's a 1-2 hours driving distance between some areas in San Francisco and some areas in San Jose (depending on the time of day).